# Ejecución de un evnto click dos veces con javascript vainilla

Tags: variables, click, funcion

tengo un código que cada vez que lo ejecuto lo realiza dos veces, he querido controlarlo con variables pero no es funcional, solicito su colaboración para entender y corregir el problema. Gracias. ÉL código es el siguiente:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  let a=document.getElementById("b1");
  a.addEventListener("click", ()=>{

  for(za=0;za<1;za++){
    let b=document.querySelectorAll(".campo, .combox");
    datos(b);
  }
 });});
```

Comment: Podés agregar un [repro] en la pregunta misma a través de un snippet. Para agregarlo, pulsá el botón que indica `<>` y agregá el HTML y JS donde corresponda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una vez revisado varias hilos de este tema encontre en este link la respuesta
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/es-ES/4d45cbe5-6677-47b6-90c3-6ad912d40e1b/evitar-que-el-evento-click-se-ejecute-dos-veces?forum=webdeves

la solución queda así

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
   let a=document.getElementById("b1");
   a.addEventListener("click", ()=>{
       e.preventDefault();
       e.stopImmediatePropagation();
      let b=document.querySelectorAll(".campo, .combox");
    datos(b);
   }
 });});
```

Primero cambie la función ()=> a function(e), luego agregue e.preventDefault(); y e.stopImmediatePropagation();, quite el for por que no es necesario.